# A compact Riemann surface with boundary strongly deformation retracting onto its boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, retraction

Let $X$ be an open Riemann surface and $K$ an open, relatively compact, connected subset of $X$. It seems to me that it is impossible for $\overline{K}$ to strongly deformation retract onto its boundary $\partial K$. (I feel that you'd have to rip it.) But if I'm right, I don't know how to convince myself of that rigorously. Or perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that you have exactly the right conditions here, but the basic idea is that even for a week homotopy equivalence, you would need $i: \partial K \hookrightarrow K$ to be a homotopy equivalence, so at the minimum they have the same homotopy groups.

Comment: I suggest you first consider $K$ whose boundary is a 1-dimensional submanifold. Then argue that $H_1(\partial K)\to H_1(K)$ is not injective (using singular homology). The general case is bone by using Chech cohomology: I am not sure if you are familiar with this.